# Check Existing File using xp_cmdshell in SQL and return a value in cmdshell

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to create a file using the SP - MSSQL. before creating a file i want to check Whether the file exist . IF Exist i want to replace a new one or else create a new file. Want to return a value while executing the cmdshell in sql.

```
               DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(100)
               DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(100)
               DECLARE @exstFile AS VARCHAR(100)

            set @cmd = 'IF EXIST Z:\AppTextFile.txt (ECHO 1) ELSE (ECHO 0)'
            EXEC @cmd = xp_cmdshell @cmd
            select @cmd datum
```

Comment: Instead of `ECHO`, try `EXIT` to set the exit code.

Comment: Why don't you use `xp_fileexist`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way for to check files existence could be to use [`xp_FileExist`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1272/file-validation-in-sql-server-with-xpfileexist-stored-procedure/):

```
DECLARE @Exists INT;

EXEC master..xp_FileExist N'U:\SSIS\Test.txt', @Exists OUTPUT

select @Exists
```

Comment: I remember this SP was working for UNC share name only and not for network drive. Is that fixed now?

Comment: Thanks bro... Thank you very much. It Worked with me well. @M.ali